# Apache-Superset variable filter chart size

Tags: apache-superset

I use  multi-select filterboxes in superset-apache by checking the box in the filter for "Allow Multiple Selections".

However upon usage I realized that while the box of the filter itself expands on selection of multiple items, the parent-box (white background + header) did not, which led to the last of my four filters being "pushed out of the box" (see screenshot) and upon selecting even more elements disappeared completely behind the chart below.

Is there a way to enable the parent box to adjust its size variably depending on its contents?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an interrim solution I used CSS in the dashboard itself:

```
.resizable-container {
     height: auto !important
}
```

This had the sideffect that **all** containers in the dashboard shrink to their content size - e.g. three different charts in one row have different lengths now (which does not look very clean...), but at least I can use multi-select filters.

Sadly the filter-containers don't have a specific css-tag so it is not possible to set their height specifically.